# How to extract media from a self-contained html file using pandoc?

Tags: html, pandoc, mediaextractor

I'm using an extension (singlefile) to save a self-contained html file then I'm trying to use pandoc to extract all media files using pandoc. I can't get it to work and I've read the manual so many times. To me it seems right. Right now the code is like that:

```
pandoc --extract-media=C:\Users\me\Downloads\teste C:\Users\me\Downloads\myhtmlfile.htm
```

Comment: A minimal, reproducible example would be really helpful here. Could you add one?

Answer (score 0):

```bash
pandoc yourIntryPointFile.html --extract-media directoryNameForMediaExported/
```

Example with a file 'index.html':

```bash
pandoc index.html --extract-media media/
```